# Word by word animation css3 or jquery

Tags: jquery, css, animation, cpu-word

I am having a content, which have to be displayed in a web page with some animations like the words should be displayed one by one as we speak. Is it possible to do this using jquery or css3?

Comment: what do you mean 'as we speak'?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible. It may depend on the speed of which you speak though. You could easily write some basic jQuery with a speed parameter that displays the words on intervals.

Here is a quick jsfiddle I wrote which does exactly this. http://jsfiddle.net/jquery4u/u4ENg/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $el = $('div'),
        text = $el.text(),
        speed = 1000; //ms

    $el.empty();

    var wordArray = text.split(' '),
        i = 0;

    INV = setInterval(function () {
        if (i >= wordArray.length - 1) {
            clearInterval(INV);
        }
        $el.append(wordArray[i] + ' ');
        i++;
    }, speed);
});
```

There is a really good [typewriter jQuery plugin](http://www.idangero.us/preview/?item=32) which acts like a Typewriter which may be of use.